# substituir texto por outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Minha duvida e a seguinte,  tenho um Button e quero trocar o seu texto pelo texto das `li` (texto das tags `<a>`) subsequentes. A principio fiz um script que não funcionou, a minha intenção resumindo, é trocar o texto do button dropdown pelo texto da `li` clicada.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="btn-group col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                <button type="button" class="selectionCalendar btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Calendario <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>                 
                <ul class="selectionCalendar dropdown-menu box-white clearfix">
                    <li ><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="WeekToday dropSelection">Hoje </a></li>
                    <li ><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="CalendarWeek dropSelection">Semana </a></li>
                    <li ><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="taskFullCalendar dropSelection"> Mês </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function trocatexto() {
    let $dropChildren = $('.dropSelection');
    let $option = $dropChildren.find('.dropSelection').text();
    $('.dropSelection').click(function () {
        $('.selectionCalendar').text($option);
    });
    }
```

Comment: "Não funcionou" no sentido de "nada aconteceu", ou aconteceu mais foi o texto errado, ou deu algum erro no console? Se a segunda opção, por qual texto foi substituído? E se a terceira, qual foi o erro no console?

Comment: nao funcionou no  sentido completo, a lista some totalmente e fica so o texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.dropSelection').click(function () {
    let $dropChildren = $('.dropSelection');
    let $option = ($(this).text());
    $('.dropdown-toggle').text($option);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
     <button type="button" class="selectionCalendar btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Calendario <span class="caret"></button>                 
     <ul class="selectionCalendar dropdown-menu box-white clearfix">
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="WeekToday dropSelection">Hoje </a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="CalendarWeek dropSelection">Semana </a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="taskFullCalendar dropSelection"> Mês </a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

> tome cuidado quando referenciar classes pois no seu HTML tem dois elementos com classe `selectionCalendar`. Isso faria trocar o texto dos dois elementos, ou seja, do `<button type="button" class="selectionCalendar btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"` e também do `<ul class="selectionCalendar dropdown-menu box-white clearfix"` Veja no exemplo a seguir:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dropSelection').click(function () {
    let $dropChildren = $('.dropSelection');
    let $option = ($(this).text());
    $('.selectionCalendar').text($option);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
     <button type="button" class="selectionCalendar btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Calendario <span class="caret"></button>                 
     <ul class="selectionCalendar dropdown-menu box-white clearfix">
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="WeekToday dropSelection">Hoje </a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="CalendarWeek dropSelection">Semana </a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#" class="taskFullCalendar dropSelection"> Mês </a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```